# The use of function stream_get_meta_data() is discouraged

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I am using Magento 2.4.6. I am getting a warning that says

> The use of function stream_get_meta_data() is discouraged

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has a core method that we can use to get the same result as stream_get_meta_data().

```
use Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\DocumentInterface;

protected $document;

public function __construct( DocumentInterface $document ) { 
   $this->document = $document;
}

public function parseData($key) { 
    $metadata = $this->document->getMetadata($key);
}
```